# Does $M$-hyponormal operator implies hyponormal if the space is finite dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B(H)$ is the space of all bounded linear operators on $H$.

> An operator $A \in B(H)$ is said to be hyponormal if $A^*A-AA^* \ge 0
> > $, where $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$.
>
> An operator $T \in B(H)$ is said to be $M$- hyponormal if there exists
>   a positive constant $M$ such that
>
> $$\|\left( T - \lambda\right)^*x \| \le M \| \left( T -
> \lambda x\right)\|,$$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in H$.

Actually, if $H$ is a finite dimensional space then any hyponormal operator is normal.

How about the case of $M$- hyponormal operator? Does it become normal or hyponormal when $\dim {H} < \infty$?

I tried to find a counter example but still not get it.

Could you please help me to find counter example or the way to prove?

Comment: Your definition of $M$-hyponormal has some typos (for one thing $M$ never appears).

Comment: thanks, I eddited

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=\mathbb C^n$.

Since the inequality is invariant by unitary conjugation, we may assume (via the [Schur Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)) that $T$ is upper triangular.

Consider first $x=e_1$, $\lambda=T_{11}$. Then $(T-\lambda I)x=0$, so 
$$
\|(T-\lambda I)^*x\|\leq M\|(T-\lambda I)x\|=0.
$$
Thus
$$
0=T^*e_1-\overline{T_{11}}\,e_1=\sum_{k=2}^n\overline{T_{1k}}e_k.
$$
So $T_{1k}=0$ for all $k\geq2$. Now let $x=e_2$, $\lambda=T_{22}$. Then, since $(T-\lambda I)x=0$, 
$$
0=(T^*-\overline{T_{22}} I)e_2=\sum_{k=3}^n\overline{T_{2k}}e_k,
$$
and it follows that $T_{23}=T_{24}=\cdots=T_{2n}=0$. By repeating this argument inductively, we obtain that $T$ is diagonal. That is, $T$ is normal.